# function and its derivative converges compactly on a open set of $R^2$ implies uniform convergence of derivative

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

> Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of continuously differentiable functions on an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose the three sequences $f_n, \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f_n}{\partial y}$ converges compactly (i.e. converges uniformly on every compact subset of domain) to functions $g, h_1$ and $h_2$, respectively. Prove that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = h_1$ and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = h_2$.

Rudin (Theorem 7.17) states that the pointwise convergence of $f_n$ and the uniform convergence of $f_n$'s partial derivatives are enough to conclude this (if I am not reading that wrong), so it is enough to show that $\partial_x f_n \to h_1$ uniformly.

So for every $x \in U$, by openness we can find a open ball $\overline{B(x, R)}$ such that it falls in $U$, so we see that by compact convergence, $\partial_x f_n \to h_1$ uniformly on this compact set.

The problem remains is that, how should I extend it to the whole $U$?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $\frac {\partial g} {\partial x}=h_1$ you take any point in $U$ and work in a neighborhood of that point. So there is no loss of generality in assuming that $U$ is bounded.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, so I updated my question to propose another issue I have now.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. I take an **arbitrary point** $(x,y) \in U$ and prove that $\frac {\partial g} {\partial x} (x,y)=h_1(x,y)$ by considering a disk around $(x,y)$ and that finishes the proof.

Comment: I should state my approach more clearly. By the theorem it suffies to show that the partial derivatives converges uniformly on *the whole $U$*, and we currently only have that the partial derivatives converges uniformly on *every compact subsets of $U$*. So my problem is, how should we "extend' the uniformness to the whole $U$.

Comment: @macton Do not apply the theorem to the open set $U$. You are free to apply it to some other open set if it helps. Apply the theorem to the disk I am considering.